# How to safely incorporate query parameters into AWS TimeStream queries in Python or Java?

Tags: java, python, sql, validation, amazon-timestream

The SQL query interface of AWS TimeStream SDKs only accepts a query string. It appears that constructing the query string, including any parameter values in where clauses and such, is left wholly to the user of the SDK, which is not the norm in languages like Python and Java.

What solutions exist for safely quoting untrusted input values for use as part of the SQL query in languages that have an AWS SDK, such as Python and Java?